# How to add a line border like this in HTML?

Tags: html, text

I'm trying to add a line border like this in HTML. I've added code to show you what I have so far. Thanks!

[Picture Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xclGD.png)

```
    <p>Hotel Guest Contact Info</p>
        <div class='div'>
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type='text' class='input' />
            <div>
        <br>
        <div class='div'>
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type='text' class='input' />
            <div>
        <br>
        <div class='div'>
            <label>Room Number:</label>
            <input type='text' class='input' />
            <div>
        <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: -

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Login</legend> 
  <table>
    <tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you Shubam! That did the trick! How would I change it so that the input boxes aren't lined up and instead are proportional to the text length?

Comment: Use CSS-  body{
 width: 100px; height: 100px;
} @Cpt_Gizmo

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Hotel Guest Contact Info</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Room Number:</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.